# Why is this virtual method's implementation chosen during compile time?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual

I've tried running the following:

```
struct B;
struct C;
struct A{
    A() { f(this);}
    virtual A* f(A* a) {
        cout << " A::f(A)" <<endl;
        return a;
    }
    void h() { cout << typeid(*this).name() << endl;}
    void g(B* b);
};

struct B:A{ 
    B() { f(this); }
    virtual A* f(A* a) {
        cout << "B::f(A)" << endl;
        return a;
    }

    virtual B* f(B* b) {
        cout << "B::f(B)" << endl;
        return b;
    }

    virtual C* f(C* c) {
        cout << "B::f(C)" << endl;
        return c;
    }
};

struct C: B{};

void A::g(B* b) { cout << typeid(*this).name() << endl; f(b);};

int main(){
    B* b = new B();
    cout << "------" << endl;
    C* c = new C();
    cout << "------" << endl;
    c->g(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that g() is non virtual so it's chosen during the compilation.

When running this I get the following output:

```
A::f(A)
B::f(B)
------
A::f(A)
B::f(B)
------
1C
B::f(A) <----- Notice this
```

Notice that the last line seems to have called f() as if it were dynamically bound but only to the method f() which A knows about (which I think has to do with the fact that g() is statically bound). 
What I expected to happen was to get B::f(B).

Why is f()'s call in g() computed at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloads have nothing to do with virtual polymorphism. Only `A::f(A*)` is virtual and dispatched dynamically. The function `B::f(B*)` is entirely unrelated.

Comment: straight and to the point.
For some reason I looked at it as if the arguments were covariant (which is obviously wrong).

Answer (score 2):

`A::g` doesn't know that `B` introduces one more *overload* of `f`. In fact, it chooses to make a virtual call to `f(A*)`, as it's the only `f` known at that place.

The virtual dispatch is done only by (invisible) -1st argument (`this`), not by any other arguments. So the function `B::f(B*)` is not taking part in the virtual chain. Therefore the actual `f(A*)` -- that is, `B::f(A*)` -- is chosen.

Calling a virtual function doesn't mean that the best matching signature is chosen an runtime, only the actual class is. The signature is chosen at compile-time (well, except return type).

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency to a derived class in your base class.  Since `A::g` is a member of `A`, it is compiled using `A`'s vtable.  It is not being "computed"  at compile time.  The dependency you created has it looking at the wrong portion of the vtable.  To clarify, `A` only has `f(A*)` defined.  It knows nothing about `f(B*)`, so there is no way for it to call it.

If you have this kind of situation in real code, you really need to think about your design.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 added the `override` keyword to help you deal with your problem here.

When you think a `virtual` method overrides a base `virtual` method, append the keyword `override` to it.

In this case, when you change `B` to contain:

```
virtual B* f(B* b) override {
    cout << "B::f(B)" << endl;
    return b;
}
```

the compiler will complain and tell you that `B* f(B*)` does not override any method in from its parents.  What you did here was introduce a new *overload*, a completely different function that happens to have the same name as the method `A* f(A*)`.

Methods with the same name participate in *overload* resolution, but do not *override* each other `virtual`ly.

Because it has the same name, you thought it was an `override` -- but in reality, it is not.  Once you realize that `B* f(B*)` is unrelated to `A* f(A*)`, everything else that happens makes perfect sense.

Overload resolution in `A` examines the options it has for `f(b)`, sees exactly one option, determines that it matches (as a `A*` argument is compatible with a `B*`), then calls it.  At this point the `virtual` function table is examined, and the proper `override` is found (which is `B::f(A*)`, the only override), which is then called.